# After submitting contact form woocommerce single page download the digital products (PDF File) sending enquiry details email to admin and client

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-product-bundles

How to integrate a contact form 7 woo-commerce product single page, after submitting digital download products (PDF File) sending enquiry details email to the admin and user.

I added the form, but am not able to download the woocommerce digital download products (PDF File) and send email from woocommerce single page.